# How to place "view online link" for salesforce HTML email templates?

Tags: email-template, html, salesforce-id

I have created an HTML email template in salesforce, now I want to place a link to view the mailer in the browser. As we place in the marketing cloud, I want to do the same in salesforce. Is there any standard solution available or we need to custom?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a content block within sfmc and pulling that in to the HTML body as a variable.

Like so

`%%=v(@contentblockname)=%%`